# Controlling App Inventor elements from JavaScript in WebViewer component

Tags: javascript, app-inventor

I'm working on an App Inventor based app which uses a lot of local HTML5 and JavaScript within WebViewer components.

Is it possible to drive App Inventor events (such as screen close and open etc) from the JavaScript within the WebViewer component and vice-versa (ie use app inventor controls to trigger functions in the JavaScript within the WebViewer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Webviewer.WebViewString` is the recommended way to pass information from App Inventor to the embedded HTML/JavaScript in the webviewer.

For the opposite direction you also can use the `Webviewer.WebViewString` or alternatively the `Webviewer.PageTitle`.

You also can trigger events in both directions:

1. from JavaScript to App Inventor: use a `Clock` component to
   check, if the `WebViewString` or `PageTitle` has been changed, e.g.
   you want to pass the text "CLOSE SCREEN" or "OPEN ANOTHER SCREEN"
   and trigger that action in App Inventor then.
2. from App Inventor to JavaScript: you will need a function in
   JavaScript, which checks the `WebViewString` and triggers some
   functions inside JavaScript then.

More information and examples:
[How does the new property Webviewer.WebViewString work?](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2webviewstring)
[Several examples, which use the WebViewString property](https://puravidaapps.com/tutorials.php#html)